# I'm new with HTML having issues with an embedded css class not working with font-style and font-weight

Tags: html

Hi I'm relatively new at web development and I'm trying to get this working for a class. The goal is to use an embedded css class to make font that is both bold and italic. So far I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--Chapter 3 ex 4, a demonstration of class-->
<html lang="en"><!--opens html and sets language to english-->
<head><!--opens head-->
<title>Chapter 3 ex 4</title><!--sets the title of the page-->
<style><!--opens embedded style-->
.new 
{   
font-weight: bold;<!--creates a class new-->
font-style: italic; <!--that is both bold and italic--> 
}
</style> <!--closes embedded style-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head> <!--Closes head-->
<body>
<p class="new">Test of new class</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the text is not being affected at all by the "new" class. I have discovered that if I remove the lang="en" from the  tag the font text becomes bold. Anyone have any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments in CSS are done with `/* your comment */` instead of the HTML style comments. Your CSS is invalid as is.

```
<!--opens embedded style-->
<style>
.new 
{   
font-weight: bold; /* creates a class new */
font-style: italic; /* that is both bold and italic */ 
}
</style> <!--closes embedded style-->
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The book didn't do a good job of explaining this.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 1):

You are using improper comments in your embedded stylesheet:

```
.new 
{       
font-weight: bold;/*creates a class new*/
font-style: italic; /*that is both bold and italic*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the `<!-- html comments -->` within the `<style>` tag it works smoothly.

Just tested it with my browser.